# Updating items in an array triggered reaction in vuejs_v2.6.12

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wonder why vue **UPDATE** changes to the page when I directly set an item with the index.
Accrding to the official document, Vue is not able to detect changes to an array when I directly set an item with the index.
My code was like

```js
const app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data(){
                return {
                    title: 'Hello, world!',
                    courses: ['Math','Literature','CS']
                }
            },
            mounted() {
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    this.title = 'Hello, vue!';
                    this.courses[1] = 'Chemistry';
                    this.courses.push('Physical');
                }, 3000);
            }
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" v-cloak>
    <h2 :title="title">
        {{title}}
    </h2>
    <div v-for="c in courses" :key="c">
        {{c}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.title = 'Hello, vue!';` and `this.courses.push('Physical');` trigger render. Then vue creates a new Vnode, where the acquired `this.courses[1]` has changed.

Try this.

```js
const app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data(){
                return {
                    title: 'Hello, world!',
                    courses: ['Math','Literature','CS']
                }
            },
            mounted() {
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    // this.title = 'Hello, vue!';
                    this.courses[1] = 'Chemistry';
                    // this.courses.push('Physical');
                }, 3000);
            }
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" v-cloak>
    <h2 :title="title">
        {{title}}
    </h2>
    <div v-for="c in courses" :key="c">
        {{c}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are changing the :key of your looping template

```
 <div v-for="c in courses" :key="c">
    {{c}}
 </div>
```

Here you have provided the array elements as key for vue to keep it in its change detection mechanism. So its reactivity is depending on the courses elements. Any change in those elements will trigger the change detection and thus the div will be updated.

If you don't want vue to change your looping elements on changing the data then I would say change your key. You can use array index for keys if you don't want any re-render but that's not a good idea.

```
 <div v-for="(c, index) in courses" :key="index">
    {{c}}
 </div>
```

Check this resource to know more about re-render mechanism in vue:  https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Comment: But, if i  don't annotate `this.title = 'Hello, vue!'` and next `push`, it still trigger the render.

Comment: Any change in courses will trigger the render for the loop and change in title will trigger render to <h2> tag because you have given them the keys for vue change detection mechanism